# How to decode Acme::Eyedrops

Tags: perl

How do I get readable code back from an [Acme::Eyedrops](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Acme-EyeDrops/lib/Acme/EyeDrops.pm) obfuscated script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation, it looks like [`sightly_to_ascii`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Acme-EyeDrops/lib/Acme/EyeDrops.pm#Function_Reference) might work.

Answer (score 3):

use B::Deparse (as in `perl -MO=Deparse proggram.pl` ) and/or replace eval with print, depending on which pattern eyedrops generates

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but for anyone finding this via Google, installing [PerlTidy](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/) from SourceForge and then running the following command line worked like a charm for me:

`perl -MO=Deparse /path/to/ObfuscatedScript.pl  | perltidy > new.pl`

This created a file called `new.pl` within my current directory with the 
acme::eyedrops code deobfuscated.